# Is there a systematic way to generate orthogonal latin squares which are not isotopic?

Tags: combinatorics

Specifically, are there non-isotopic sets of orthogonal latin squares for n = 5?
If so, is there a systematic way of generating them?

Comment: I had some comments but deleted them when I realized I don't know what "not isotopic" means. Couldn't find definition by a quick search-- coud you add one or supply a link to one? Thanks.